# Create/access nested tables in lua via C/C++

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

how to create nested tables? My approach sadly does not work. I thought that **lua_newtable** pushes a new table on the stack and if I do **lua_settable** that should set key value pair, but I was mistaken apparently.

```
/* 
 * local transform = GetTransform()
 * print("Translation: " .. transform.Translation.x)
 */

lua_newtable(L);
int index = lua_gettop(L);
lua_pushstring(L, "Translation");
{
    lua_newtable(L); // Table inside table

    lua_pushstring(L, "x");
    lua_pushvalue(L, 0);
    lua_settable(L, -3);

    lua_pushstring(L, "y");
    lua_pushvalue(L, 0);
    lua_settable(L, -3);

    lua_pushstring(L, "z");
    lua_pushvalue(L, 0);
    lua_settable(L, -3);
}
lua_settable(L, index);
```

Comment: C or C++. Pick one please.

Comment: Are you talking about a 3d matrix or array?

Comment: Your code looks correct.  What exactly "does not work"?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I woke up and noticed that I used **lua_pushvalue** instead of **lua_pushnumber**. 
Thanks for help :D